# Find lowest fraction of perimeter and area of a rectangle.

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, area

Let $D$ be a rectangle with dimensions $a \times b$, where $b>a$ and its surface area is 1. In rectangle $D$ we have a square with side $a$ so we obtain a smaller rectangle $E$ if we cut off this square from $D$. Let $p$ be the perimeter of $E$ and $S$ its surface area. Find $D$ such as $\frac p S$ is the lowest possible value.
How can I find it? By limits? If so how should I proceed?

Comment: What is $o$?  What is $s$?  What have you done on the problem so far?

Comment: What is $o{}{}$?

Comment: Start by labeling everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s known that $$ab=1$$ $E$ has dimensions $b-a$ and $a$, so $$p=2(b-a+a) =2b \\ S= a(b-a) $$ and $$\frac pS = \frac{2b}{a(b-a)} =\frac{2}{a^2(1/a -a)} = \frac{2}{a(1-a^2)}$$ To minimize this, you need to maximize $$a(1-a^2)$$ Can you do this using calculus? Keep in mind that $b\gt a \iff \frac 1a \gt a \iff a^2 \lt 1 \iff a\lt 1$

Comment: so in fact, it is dependent only on $a$ and $b$ does not matter

Comment: @Rikib161999 It is dependent in both. I could have instead substituted for $a$ and written everything using $b$.

Comment: oh yes, I see...

Comment: so I basicaly need to find maximu of function $f(a)=a(1-a*a)$ and value of $a$ in it (on interval (0,1)) and $b=1-a$ then, am I right?

Comment: @Rikib161999 Right

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)